# Multiple files and structs, differing outputs

Tags: c

In this small program, all three files all have different responsibilities.

The goal of the program is to read data from the data.c file into the struct array created in testing.h, which can be then accessed and used in testing.c.

What I am finding is that when I attempt to print outside the local scope and furthermore attempt to print outside the file the output changes.

**data.c**

```
void data() { 
    size_t friends[] = {1,3,4};
    userdata[0].friends_ids = friends;

    size_t friends2[] = {5,8,9};
    userdata[1].friends_ids = friends2;
}
```

**testing.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "testing.h"
#include "data.c"

int main() {
    data();

    for (int x=0; x<3; x++) {
        printf("%d\n", userdata[0].friends_ids[x]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int x=0; x<3; x++) {
        printf("%d\n", userdata[1].friends_ids[x]);
    }
}
```

**testing.h**

```
struct user {
size_t* friends_ids;
};
struct user userdata[2];
```

Output:

```
1
3
4

-1942895168
1680886992
-320301600
```

It's evident these are garbage values for userdata[1] but I am confused why does userdata[0] print correctly but userdata[1] outputs garbage values?

What I've tried is to allocate memory for the structs but I don't know if it's possible because I keep getting errors saying "initializer element is not constant" despite trying.

```
struct user *userdata = (struct user *)malloc(2*sizeof(struct user));
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined, you cannot reason it.

Comment: `friends` and `friends2` are local scope arrays.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. Undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: *"Somebody once told me that in basketball you can’t hold the ball and run. I got a basketball and tried it and it worked just fine. He obviously didn’t understand basketball."*

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now, out of interest why was it printing the first output correctly? Any reason?

Comment: Because the old stack frame from the call to `data` (including its local variables) had only got partially clobbered by the later code, and `friends` managed to survive. Don't count on it!

Comment: @RhodriMorgan re-read my first comment.

Comment: `size_t` is probably not what you want your array to contain. Its size in bytes varies depending on 32 or 64 bit. I would use a fixed size integer like uint32_t or uint64_t depending on the range of values you need, and assuming they will all be positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there is the potential for *[undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)* in the posted code, but I did not get that far as the posted code resulted in a run-time error: *defreferencing out of bounds pointer* on the first call to `printf` in the `main` function. (possibly due to UB)

Problems (and suggested fixes) are listed below.

```
void data() {...
```

Is not a valid function prototype, and should have thrown a warning.  And for your purposes, even:

```
void data(void) {...
```

although valid, is not sufficient.  Change it to:

```
void data(struct user User[2]) {...
```

By the way also the minimum signature for the `main` function prototype is:

```
int main(void){...
```

Once you have made these changes, and given your definition of `struct user` ,consider the additional edits to `data` and `main`: (note, the following suggestions are limited only to illustrate one method of using function arguments to pass/receive data.  Program architecture, or other ways to define a `struct` are left for other discussions.)

```
void data(struct user User[2]) // pass struct as argument
{
    size_t i;
    int a[] = {1,2,3};
    int b[] = {4,5,6};

    for(i=0;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);i++)
    {
        userdata[0].friends_ids[i] = a[i];  
        userdata[1].friends_ids[i] = b[i];
    }
}

int main(void) {

    userdata[0].friends_ids = calloc(3, sizeof(size_t)); // create memory
    userdata[1].friends_ids = calloc(3, sizeof(size_t));

    data(&userdata[2] ); //populate struct pointers (pass pointer to struct)

    // values returned from call to data() are refreshed and ready to use.
    for (int x=0; x<3; x++) { // use struct data
        printf("%d\n", userdata[0].friends_ids[x]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int x=0; x<3; x++) {
        printf("%d\n", userdata[1].friends_ids[x]);
    }

    free(userdata[0].friends_ids); // free memory
    free(userdata[1].friends_ids);

    return 0;
}
```